# Display multiple images in java with SWING and and place them separately in the same window

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to display an image in the same window and display another image *on* the old one without erasing it to superimpose them using JFrame.

Here is the updated code. I can display multiple image, but I can’t display the new one on the old one and I can’t make it in the X column and Y line.

How can I fix it?

```java
package morpion;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUI extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6398802531018487402L;

    public GUI(char [][]array, int taille)
    {
        ImageIcon board = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("tictactoe.jpg"));
        ImageIcon x = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("X.PNG"));
        ImageIcon o = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("O.PNG"));

        JLabel board1 = new JLabel(board);
        JLabel x1 = new JLabel(x);
        JLabel o1 = new JLabel(o);

        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3, 3);

        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("TicTacToe(Morpion)");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(535, 560);
        setLocation(200, 0);
        setVisible(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(panel);
        panel.setLayout(grid);

        panel.add(x1);
        panel.add(o1);
        panel.add(board1);

        FlowLayout game = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10);
        getContentPane().setLayout(game);
    }

}
```

Comment: Just to be clear: You want to super impose the images?  How does that work, just draw one on top of the other?  What if the images are not transparent?

Comment: Looks like you are create tic-tac-toe game, then you need to create 9 labels and add them to the panel in a `GridLayout`. Then you can add an "X" or "O" Icons to a label.

Comment: markspace my png have a white backcround so they are not transparent if they are super impose we will not see the difference

camickr i will try when im home thanks but how can i place the label to a specifi area ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved. We just need to fuse the board and the X or O, and fuse the result with the next token.